# How to run 2 flask apps and Nginx using a single docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, flask

I’m looking to run 2 flask containers and 1 Nginx container using one docker compose file but keep getting 404 errors.

Tried following a number of tutorials but still no luck.

Below is my docker compose file along with Nginx.conf and Uwsgi config.

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    flask:
        build: ./flask
        container_name: flask
        restart: always
        image: flask
        environment: 
            - APP_NAME=flask
        expose: 
            - 8080
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"

    flask2:
        build: ./flask2
        container_name: flask2
        restart: always
        image: flask2
        environment: 
            - APP_NAME=flask2
        expose: 
            - 8081
        ports: 
            - "8081:8081"

    nginx: 
        build: ./nginx
        image: nginx
        container_name: nginx
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "81:81"
        depends_on: 
            - flask
            - flask2
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream flask_app1 {
    server flask:8080;
}

upstream flask_app2 {
    server flask2:8081;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location /test1 {
        uwsgi_pass flask_app1;
    }

    location /test2 {
        uwsgi_pass flask_app2;
    }
}
```

uwsgi: Both identical except port.

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = run.py
callable = app
socket = :8081
processes = 4
threads = 2
master = true
chmod-socket = 660
buffer-size = 32768
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

I’m using docker for windows and I can see in the GUI that the 2 flask apps have ports binded at 8080 and 8081 and nginx being binded to port 80.

Not sure what the else the issue could be. Any help would be fantastic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what url you are asking? `localhost/task1` and `localhost/task2`? And when you ask `localhost:8080` or `localhost:8081` it works?

Comment: @d0niek looking for url `locoalhost/test1` and `localhost/test2`. I can try adsrees with pots such as `localhost:8080` and i get nothing.

Comment: If url `localhost:8080` not works then url `localhost/task1` won't works too

Comment: Pleae edit your question to add the docker-compose logs.

Answer (score 0):

Although I was not able to get what I ideally wanted by routing each appliaction to a different location I did managed to solve the issue by setting the ports for nginx in the docker-compose file to the ports I wanted to use for each app and then using individual server blocks to route the ports to the ports each app is communicating on.

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    flask:
        build: ./flask
        container_name: flask
        restart: always
        image: flask
        environment: 
            - APP_NAME=flask

    flask2:
        build: ./flask2
        container_name: flask2
        restart: always
        image: flask2
        environment: 
            - APP_NAME=flask2

    nginx: 
        build: ./nginx
        image: nginx
        container_name: nginx
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8001:8001"
            - "8002:8002"
        depends_on: 
            - flask
            - flask2
```

nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 8001;
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass flask:8001;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8002;
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass flask:8002;
    }
}
```